# Is there a way to find whether theuser is using Wayland instead of X11, WITHOUT enviroment variables? (C)

Tags: c, linux, sdl, wayland, xwayland

I am currently working with C and SDL2, and I need to know whether Wayland is currently used as the windowing system (Obviously because I want to use Wayland, but SDL2 defaults to Xwayland). While `SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland` does work, it won't work if you are in X11, saying that the video driver is unavailable. So, what I am looking for, is a low-level way of getting the current windowing system (Possibly by asking the compositor?) on GNU/Linux. It also needs to be unmodifiable, that is, no application or user will be able to change it unless the session ends.

Comment: Determining how to reach the compositor _always_ involves environment variables. If `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` is unset, it uses `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to find the directory relative to which to locate the socket to use, or if that's unset, calculates a default relative to `HOME`.

Comment: Mind, you can ask the kernel which environment variables a process was _started with_, so walk up the process tree to the first process within a user's session and the "unmodifiable" criteria can be met even with environment variables in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize SDL with no subsystem via `SDL_Init(0)` then ask SDL to connect to whatever Wayland session is running via `SDL_VideoInit("wayland")`; if that call succeeds you're good to go with the usual `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)` & window creation.

Though for more robustness you should iterate over the `SDL_GetNumVideoDrivers()`/`SDL_GetVideoDriver()` string list to verify the SDL install in use was even built with Wayland support.

See the test program [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57684805/44729) for video driver enumeration & testing.

Comment: If `SDL_VideoInit("wayland")` refers to environment variables, can you really say this is "WITHOUT environment variables"?

Comment: Nope, that should actually try to connect to the Wayland session, not *just* check some ennvars.

Comment: Right, but my point is that the actually trying to connect involves environment variables, because that's how the library being invoked finds the socket to connect to. (There's a default location, but there's an environment variable that's checked to determine whether it should be overridden, _and_ that default is defined relative to the location pointed at by a different environment variable).

Comment: @genpfault What happens on failure though? What if there is no Wayland session at all, or it simply fails to detect one?

Comment: @AggelosT: `SDL_VideoInit()` returns an error value and you keep moving down the `SDL_GetNumVideoDrivers()`/`SDL_GetVideoDriver()` list trying other drivers until one (or none) of them work.